# Cytoscape: Use more than an attribute?

Tags: node.js, networking, attributes, cytoscape

I'm working with Cytoscape, and I need to use more than an attribute for each node, possibly duplicating the nodes.

Is it possible?

If I upload the "attribute file" with more than an attribute, I can use only one attribute for each node.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upload a file that has 100's of attributes for any given node.  Can you tell us what version of Cytoscape you are using and how you are trying to upload your node attributes?

-- scooter